# ML estimation of Rician distribution parameters in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have data samples arranged in a 1000 x 56 array, and I would like to extract the parameters of a Rician distribution that best fits the data in each column.  I am using the `VGAM` package, which seems like a perfect fit, and given the example in the documentation for `riceff`

```
vee = exp(2); sigma = exp(1);
y = rrice(n <- 1000, vee, sigma)
fit = vglm(y ~ 1, riceff, trace=TRUE, crit="c")
```

I figured the following code would work without a problem

```
nu <- rep(-1,ncol(data))
sigma <- rep(-1,ncol(data))

for( coln in seq(ncol(data)) ) {
  fdata <- c(data[,coln])
  fit <- vglm( fdata ~ 1, riceff, trace=TRUE, crit="c" )
  sigma[coln] <- matrix(Coef(fit)[1])[1,1]
  nu[coln] <- matrix(Coef(fit)[2])[1,1]
}
```

but instead I get the error

```
VGLM    linear loop  1 :  coefficients = -723936.834084,     598.301767
Error in if ((temp <- sum(wz[, 1:M, drop = FALSE] < wzepsilon))) warning(paste(temp,  : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

as for my data, I ran some basic checks

```
> is.matrix(data)
[1] TRUE
> dim(data)
[1] 1000   56
> summary(data)
       V1           
 Min.   :1.402e-05  
 1st Qu.:9.533e-04  
 Median :1.548e-03  
 Mean   :1.640e-03  
 3rd Qu.:2.175e-03  
 Max.   :4.657e-03  

 ... (omitted for brevity)

      V56           
 Min.   :5.252e-05  
 1st Qu.:1.125e-03  
 Median :1.692e-03  
 Mean   :1.776e-03  
 3rd Qu.:2.293e-03  
 Max.   :5.903e-03
```

None of the information in the summary indicates that there is a `NaN` hidden somewhere, so I am at a loss as to why vglm is failing.

Does anyone have an idea as to what may be the problem? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should add that is I define my data via `data <- matrix(rrice(56000,exp(2),exp(1)),1000,56)` I don't get the error message, but if I use `data <- 10^(read.table(filename,quote="\"",sep=",")/20)` to read my data in, then I get the above error message (my data is a CSV file of samples in dBs)

Comment: your comment is very helpful.  Since VGAM uses numerical optimization there is always the possibility that it will fail on odd data.  I would put a `try` statement into your loop that will insert `NA` values if the fit fails -- then go back and examine the data for those cases and see if there's something distinctive.

Comment: Looks like you are right, Ben. the Rician fitting procedure breaks down in the Rayleigh limit, and that is the regime of some of my data. Looks like I will have to try a Rician fit and if that fails, do a Rayleigh fit.

Comment: OK, do you want to go ahead and document your solution as an answer? (I'll upvote it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As suggested by Ben Bolker, here is the "solution" to my own problem (for future reference):*

The `vglm` function in the `VGAM` package does not necessarily behave well for all data inputs. Since a lot of data is often close to being Rayleigh distributed, the command just exits with that bizarre error (Koay inversion also fails, for similar reasons I assume). If I fit my data against a generalized Rayleigh distribution via `genrayleigh`, everything works well enough.

One way to try both, as Ben suggested, is to use `try` or `tryCatch` to attempt both, or to emit `NA` values when the fitting function breaks down.

```
tryCatch( {
  fit <- vglm( fdata ~ 1, riceff, trace=TRUE, crit="c" )
  # extract fit parameters here
  # ...
}, error = function(ex) {
  # insert NA value into your data here
  # ...
} )
```